# iPhone: duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain

Tags: iphone, ios, conflicting-libraries, layar, brightcove

I want to use the Brightcove library and the Layar library in one application, which both have the SBJson files. Obviously these try to murder each other dead.

Do i have to extract the files and rebuild the archives? I'm on a tight deadline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove one of the duplicate files from the target

Comment: Yeah, well I extracted one .a and removed the SBJSon files, however now I get these duplicate errors for one in Library X and the other in the DerivedData folder?

Comment: I'd delete the DerivedData folder... xcode will rebuild it :)

Comment: That's what i thought! I still got the DerivedData duplicate.

Comment: hm.. if you have both only in compiled form you are out of luck I guess .. you have to rebuild one of the libraries

Comment: And don't forget to complain over this badly managed namespacing in the brigthcove support forums.