# duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain youtube iphone app

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

I am trying to integrate youtube in my application , i followed all the steps as mentioned in the http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/

now when i try to build the code it is trowing the error as 
duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in both Gdatalibrary.0 and SBJsonBase.o for architecture i386.

I have SBJson file in facebook sdk as well. when i try to remove file from one of the framework whether from youtube Gdata Api or facebook API both gives me error as missing file.

Kindly help me with this.

Thank You!

P.S. 
I have tried solutions given by 
[iPhone error ld: duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in /Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework/PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036897/iphone-error-ld-duplicate-symbol-sbjsonerrordomain-in-users-shared-phonegap-f)

[iPhone: duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776202/iphone-duplicate-symbol-sbjsonerrordomain)
this link says Hard luck!

Please help i am stuck due to this!

thank You!

Comment: does your target have more than one files added to it with the same name..? If yes try removing it and then check... this usually works for me.

Comment: Actually App has JSon library in both youtube and facebook library. But when i build the project it gives duplicate error. When i remove file from one of the library it gives missing files error.

Comment: how many targets does your project has.. ?

Comment: ther is only one target in project...

Comment: I am facing the almost same issue. I had JSON framework in my app and all json parsing is done by that framework. now when I am trying to integrate the FacebookSDK framework it is showing duplicate symbol error in FBSBJsonbase.o.. Please providesome solution if any one fixed this issue.